# How to use the ENTIRE A4 page in LateX

Tags: fullwidth, fullpage

Can someone please provide the code that makes me use the entire A4 page? I don't want it to be pretty, I just want to use the entire A4 page.

Right now I have the following three lines which doesn't do the job for me.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
```

Comment: Try `\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}` and `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}`.  Forget the `fullpage` package, unless you have another reason to use it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you know about the `savetrees` package?

Comment: What's the application?

Comment: @egreg Thank you but the answer is no I don't know the savetrees package... I am just a beginner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As indicated in my comment, the paper can be specified as an optional argument to `\documentclass` and the margin can be specified as an optional argument to `\usepackage{geometry}`.  In my MWE, I have also included `\pagestyle{empty}`, to eliminate the use of page numbering, which itself creates a bit of blank space.

Now whether your printer can print such a page is another question, as most printers require a certain minimal margin.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I start from scratch that is working but in my current document I have also used some formula's but I still get some text outside the A4 page which I can't see. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @Amanda -- i don't think we can guess what is happening unless we can see the code that causes the text to go outside the page. copy the file to another name, then remove everything in the test but a paragraph or two where the problem occurs.  that should get a very fast reaction.

Comment: @Amanda  As barbara says, an example of the code that extends outside the page would be helpful to know.  However, know that math equations will *not* auto-wrap.  So, if you are typesetting a particularly long equation, it will continue to extend off the margins, unless you take proactive steps to break the equation into multiple lines.